# data lost in simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I am reading xml with this code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

it reads correctly, and can access to data via $xml->title etc. 
but i need to access to CDATA and `<media:xxx>` tags.

example of xml: [pastie](http://pastie.org/1136312)
from: http://www.metacafe.com/api/item/4779040/

is possible to parse that data? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$namespacesMeta = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$mediaXML = $xml->children($namespacesMeta['media']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into SimpleXml and Namespaces

Try this - http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302